# Latency measurement of each level of memory hierarchy

Tags: c, caching, bit-manipulation, latency

I want to measure the latency of each memory hierarchy level, from L1 to the main memory. So,  I was trying to understand the 1-single.c program at https://gist.github.com/jiewmeng/3787223. Why is the index of the array being calculated by [(i * 16) & lengthMod]?

Values of [(i * 16) & lengthMod] and i*16 will always be same. For example,

```
i=0, [(i * 16) & lengthMod]=0, [i*16]=0
i=1, [(i * 16) & lengthMod]=16, [i*16]=16
i=2, [(i * 16) & lengthMod]=32, [i*16]=32
i=3, [(i * 16) & lengthMod]=48, [i*16]=48
i=4, [(i * 16) & lengthMod]=64, [i*16]=64
i=5, [(i * 16) & lengthMod]=80, [i*16]=80
.........................................
```

So, I tried to run the program replacing [(i * 16) & lengthMod] with [i * 16], but, the program crashed every time. That's how I realized there must be a solid reason behind this bit-wise operation. Can anyone please explain why array is being calculated by [(i * 16) & lengthMod]?

Answer (score 0):

In the `for` loop:

```
for (i = 0; i < steps; i++) {
    arr[(i * 16) & lengthMod] *= 10;
```

`steps` is 256 MB and `arr[]` has 4 MB of elements. Thus if you change the array access to `arr[i * 16]` you will quickly overflow the array and enter undefined behaviour territory.

In the original code you have:

```
lengthMod = sizes[s] - 1;
```

where `sizes[]` is defined to hold various powers of 2 up to 4MB. Thus, when you do `(i * 16) & lengthMod` you are ensuring that the array access never equals or exceeds `sizes[s]` and therefore preventing an array overflow from occurring.

Answer (score 0):

In most of recent processors Cache line size is 64B

Array elements indices are 0,1,2...
one element 4B
Cacheline size / one element size = 64/4 =16

each cache line has 16 elements (=> 64B)
So it will be like array 0 to 15 elements in cacheline 0
16 to 31 elements in cacheline 1
32 to 47 elements in cacheline 2  ...

If you access any element then the cacheline of that element will be brought to memory.

So accessing 0th element bring cacheline0 into cache
accessing 16th element will bring next cache line1 into cache..

You need not access all elements ; you just need to access one element of a cache line to bring all other 15 elements!!

Thats why you saw there *16